# Query MSGraph API with PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod does not return same amount of details as MSGraph Explorer

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I used MSGraph Explorer and PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod to query the same MSGraph API, but MSGraph Explorer returns way more details than the PowerShell command. Could this be a permission issue or I missed something in the PowerShell command.

Here is the URI, it is to retrieve the audit log for a particular directory change.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits/Directory_029A8_49125229
```

This is the output from MSGraph Explorer:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits/$entity",
    "id": "Directory_029A8_49125229",
    "category": "Core Directory",
    "correlationId": "d534994f-61f4-4015-8040-c16f728ec8b3",
    "result": "success",
    "resultReason": "",
    "activityDisplayName": "Update user",
    "activityDateTime": "2018-10-04T05:41:19.9668303Z",
    "loggedByService": null,
    "initiatedBy": {
        "app": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "1f5c2159-f515-4cea-a99c-11c6ce1f7a5e",
            "displayName": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "tom-admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "ipAddress": "<null>"
        }
    },
    "targetResources": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.targetResourceUser",
            "id": "498b3884-f723-444c-9c01-b75ec2c0ef08",
            "displayName": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "Tom.Real@contoso.com",
            "modifiedProperties": [
                {
                    "displayName": "AssignedLicense",
                    "oldValue": "[\"[SkuName=ENTERPRISEPACK, AccountId=cdc4b90d-7fa9-4a, SkuId=6f94b900, DisabledPlans=[]]\"]",
                    "newValue": "[]"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "AssignedPlan",
                    "oldValue": "[{\"SubscribedPlanId\":..., \"ServicePlanId\":\"50e68c76-46c6-4674-81f9-75456511b170\"}]",
                    "newValue": "[{\"SubscribedPlanId\":... 50e68c76-46c6-4674-81f9-75456511b170\"}]"
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
                    "oldValue": null,
                    "newValue": "\"AssignedLicense, AssignedPlan\""
                },
                {
                    "displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
                    "oldValue": null,
                    "newValue": "\"Member\""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "additionalDetails": [
        {
            "key": "UserType",
            "value": "Member"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the output from Invoke-RestMethod:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/directoryAudits/$entity",
"id": "Directory_029A8_49125229",
"category": "Core Directory",
"correlationId": "d534994f-61f4-4015-8040-c16f728ec8b3",
"result": "success",
"resultReason": "",
"activityDisplayName": "Update user",
"activityDateTime": "2018-10-04T05:41:19.9668303Z",
"loggedByService": null,
"initiatedBy": {
"app": null,
"user": {
"id": "1f5c2159-f515-4cea-a99c-11c6ce1f7a5e",
"displayName": null,
"userPrincipalName": "tom-admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
"ipAddress": "\u003cnull\u003e"
}
},
"targetResources": [
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.targetResourceUser",
"id": "498b3884-f723-444c-9c01-b75ec2c0ef08",
"displayName": null,
"userPrincipalName": "Tom.Real@contos.com",
"modifiedProperties": " "
}
],
"additionalDetails": [
{
"key": "UserType",
"value": "Member"
}
]
}
```

As you can see Invoke-RestMethod does not return any details under "additionalDetails".

This is my PowerShell script

```
Function GetAuthToken
{
    param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $TenantName
        )
    Import-Module Azure
    $clientId = "ef9bcdf0-a675-4cd5-9ec3-fa549f9ee4cf" 
    $redirectUri      = "https://RedirectURI.com" 
    $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName"
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    $Credential = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\MIMA\tom_admin_cred.xml"
    $AADCredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential" -ArgumentList $credential.UserName,$credential.Password
    $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId,$AADCredential)
    return $authResult
}
    if($Version -eq $null) {$Version='Beta'}
    #------Get the authorization token------#
    $token = GetAuthToken -TenantName $tenant 

    #------Building Rest Api header with authorization token------#
    $authHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'='application\json'
        'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
        }

    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/directoryAudits/Directory_029A8_49125229"
     $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Get
     $results |ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe everything is fine with your query and permissions, the results are different since for [`ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) *by default*  2 levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation.

So, if you want `directoryAudit` all properties to be included in result, `Depth` parameter needs to be specified explicitly, for example:

```
$results |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3   #at least 3 levels for directoryAudit entry
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved! It will be interesting to know if there is a way to get all levels of objects without knowing how many levels the output will have.